# Rearrange stackpanels with a number of items in them - WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I currently have seven different panels with buttons, textboxes, and other items in them. Each panel is long horizontally and are stacked on top of each other currently and all of the panels are inside of a scroll viewer and start out not visible. Above the scroll viewer is a listbox with the names of each of the seven different panels and when one is selected, that panel is made visible. I am trying to find a way so that when a panel is selected from the listbox, it moves that panel to the top of the scroll viewer.  I have looked at items control examples but they do not say how to control multiple items in groups or panels in this case. Sorry if this is a bit confusing, thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have viewmodels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, which main container panel are you using in `ScrollViewer` ? As you have said, 7 panels are stacked, so I am assuming you have a `StackPanel` inside `ScrollViewer`.

Now, you need to manipulate `Children collection` of `StackPanel`.
Eg;

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,61,0,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="MainPnl">
             ... 7 panels ...
            </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer
```

Code :

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
        string name = (item as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();

        Panel pnl = FindName(name) as Panel;

        int indexof = MainPnl.Children.IndexOf(pnl);
        MainPnl.Children.RemoveAt(indexof);

        MainPnl.Children.Insert(0, pnl);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! This is exactly what I was looking for.